# Error in loading WebEditCommand after upgrade from 7.5 to 8.0

Tags: upgrade

We are in process of upgrading incrementally from 7.5 to 8.1.

After upgrading from 7.5 to 8.0. When we try to access the content editor, index manager we get the below error. Please see screenshots and log files attached.

> Could not load type 'Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Commands.WebEditCommand' from assembly 'Sitecore.Client, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

[image: Upgrade Errror]

Answer (score 3):

We recently faced a similar issue, it was caused by one of our custom commands we had, which was inheriting this type '**Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Commands.WebEditCommand, Sitecore.Client**',  We got rid of it as we didnt need it and it fixed the issue, Or you can update your custom command to inherit the class from the new assembly in **Sitecore.ExperienceEditor** assembly (Same class name and namespace)

Note, that there is a chance that you have a custom module (marketplace module) installed which still uses the old WebEditCommand, Try disabling all modules you have and see which one is causing this.

Comment: so does it mean `WebEditCommand` is removed from Sitecore 8.1 ?

Comment: @HarshBaid It has been moved from Sitecore.Client to Sitecore.ExperienceEditor assembly

Answer (score 2):

You should verify if the dll's in your bin folder are the ones from the Sitecore version you are on (8.0). Errors like this happen very often and are almost always caused by dll's in the bin folder that are still from the old Sitecore version.

Download the zip of a clean Sitecore with the exact version you are on. Unzip and compare the dll's in the bin with your bin. You can do the compare manually (can, but won't) or use any compare tool you are used to.

If you find any inconsistencies, overwrite the dll in your bin folder with the one from the clean Sitecore.

Also, make sure that if you deploy to your environment no dll's are overwritten again. Check your references (or update if using Nuget - which you should) and sometimes it is also needed to clean (delete) all bin and obj folders hanging around in your projects.

Comment: hi check @Ahmed's answer here http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/2464/172

Answer (score 1):

Use [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php) to compare your bin folder to an out of the 8.0 bin folder. I think you have some dlls that are wrong, but named the same. You should also compare the /sitecore folder.

When upgrading, I generally like to install a new Sitecore site and deploy the upgraded codebase into it. It helps to lower the risk of errors like this.

The dlls that are wrong may be coming from your deployment. So they were right, but a deployment overwrote them. In development, you should use the new Sitecore NuGet server. https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/sitecore_public_nuget_packages_faq. This will help to ensure you have the correct dlls throughout the deployment process.

Comment: hi check @Ahmed's answer here http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/2464/172

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of that error by disabling `Sitecore.forms.config`. Probably because the wffm was not updated and I now need to update wffm to version 8.