# Could not load type 'Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Commands.WebEditCommand'

Tags: content-editor, experience-editor

I am working on a Sitecore 8.1 site. I was given a zipped package with the Website folder in it and I am trying to get it set-up on our Development server.

The website itself works fine and I can log into the Sitecore admin where I can view the Sitecore Experience Platform home page. The problem is that clicking on any of the following Sitecore applications results in a `Server Error in '/' Application` with the exception described below:

- Content Editor
- Experience Editor
- Media Library
- Workbox
- Recycle Bin
- Access Viewer
- Domain Manager
- User Manager
- Security Editor
- Role Manager
- Desktop

**Exception Details:**

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Commands.WebEditCommand' from assembly 'Sitecore.Client, Version=8.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
[TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Commands.WebEditCommand' from assembly 'Sitecore.Client, Version=8.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +60
   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(String assembly, String className, Object[] parameters) +64
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.CommandManager.ReadCommands() +662
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.CommandManager..cctor() +68

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.CommandManager' threw an exception.]
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.CommandManager.GetCommand(String name) +0
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.FillParamsFromCommand(CommandContext commandContext, RibbonCommandParams ribbonCommandParams) +62
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.GetCommandParameters(Item controlItem, CommandContext commandContext) +79
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderLargeButton(HtmlTextWriter output, Item button, CommandContext commandContext) +78
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderButton(HtmlTextWriter output, Item button, CommandContext commandContext) +398
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderChunk(HtmlTextWriter output, Item chunk, CommandContext commandContext) +345
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderChunk(HtmlTextWriter output, Item chunk, CommandContext commandContext, Boolean isContextual, String id) +244
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderChunk(HtmlTextWriter output, Item chunk, CommandContext commandContext, Boolean isContextual) +161
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderChunks(HtmlTextWriter output, Item strip, CommandContext commandContext, Boolean isContextual) +421
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderStrips(HtmlTextWriter output, Item ribbon, Boolean isContextual, ListString visibleStripList) +1917
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderStrips(HtmlTextWriter output, Item defaultRibbon, Item contextualRibbon, ListString visibleStripList) +162
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) +800
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +80
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +160
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +11828405
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +47
   Sitecore.Web.FormAdapter.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +76
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +116
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +50
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +160
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +47
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +80
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +160
   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +39
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +80
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +8921
```

Comment: Try disabling `.config` file of any additional modules in your Sitecore instance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should Try disabling .config file of any additional modules in your Sitecore instance. Since it's possible that some module is built by old `WebEditCommand` which was in `Sitecore.Client.dll` whereas in Sitecore 8 it's moved in `Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.dll` as suggested here https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/2464/172

Comment: Disabling the Digizuite config file fixed the error.

Answer (score 4):

This is either a bad config or a bad dll. And by bad I mean wrong version.

1. Backup your bin directory.
2. Open the file sitecore\shell\sitecore.version.xml to find the real version that you are expected to be running.
3. Download the proper Sitecore.zip file for the version from step 2.
4. Copy the bin folder from the zip and overwrite your existing bin directory and test.

If that doesn't resolve the problem, follow these steps.

1. Download [Beyond Compare](https://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php).
2. Open the zip file from from above and extract the App_Config folder.
3. Use beyond compare and compare the extracted App_Config folder and one from your website. There will be difference depending on how diciplined your team is about using patch files. But you should be able to see config files that are missing or are wildly different.

If you find that the issue is dlls, you should check your deployments for this site to make sure that bad dlls are not coming from development. Also use [Sitecore's NuGet](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/sitecore_public_nuget_packages_faq) for your references in Visual studio. This will help keep them are the right and specific versions.